# NSM Better Meta & Using EE Layouts

Tags: template-layouts, metadata, layouts

What is the propper way to use NSM better meta and layouts?

At the moment, my layout has the NSM tag in the head, I've wrapped some channel entry tags around it. Not sure if this is the correct way to use it?

```
{exp:channel:entries require_entry="yes" limit="1" dynamic="yes"}
{exp:nsm_better_meta:template entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I also have another problem, how do I deal with the homepage? I can't seem to pull any nsm data through.

The homepage entry_id is 1, with a status of hidden.

When I was using embeds I used...

```
{embed="/includes/head" title_prefix="Site" hide_site_title="y" entry_id="1"}
```

But with layouts I can't use those parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a [layout variable](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/templates/layouts.html#dynamic-variables) for the `entry_id`, then instruct NSM Better Meta to use that if it exists.

In your entry template:

```
{layout:set name="entry_id" value="{entry_id}"}
```

(This would have to be within a `channel:entries` loop obviously.)

Then in your layout template:

```
{exp:nsm_better_meta:template{if layout:entry_id} entry_id="{layout:entry_id}"{/if}}
```

Comment: Hi Derek, that's great, that's the conclusion I've come to now, but I wasn't sure if it was correct. I do have a problem though, is that it means me having to explicity set the layout variable in every template, which means for whatever reason If I had a re-jig I'd have to physically change it in every template, is there a way around this, an alternative etc?

Comment: I have to put a space after {exp:nsm_better_meta:template (the word template) otherwise I get an error.

Comment: NSM Better Meta needs to know which entry to pull content from somehow, so any solution will involve specifying the entry ID somewhere (be it in a layout variable, an embed variable, or otherwise).